# How to set Expect-CT via PHP header method?

Tags: php, google-chrome, security, header, certificate

Is it possible to set Chrome's Certificate Transparency Policy [Expect-CT](https://scotthelme.co.uk/a-new-security-header-expect-ct/) via [PHP header](http://php.net/manual/de/function.header.php)?

i.e like this?

```
 header("Expect-CT: enforce; max-age=30; report-uri='https://scotthelme.report-uri.io/r/default/ct/enforce'");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that works:

```
header("Expect-CT: enforce; max-age=30; report-uri='https://YOURDOMAIN.report-uri.io/r/default/ct/enforce'");
```